# Possible to change background color depending on day of the week using only arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I change the background colour of the body using only arrays? Is this possible? 
I know how to do it with if statements or switch statements, but arrays?

Here is my attempt.

```
 <?php 
   $days = array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow", "black", "purple", "white"); 
   $today = date('w'); 
   echo '<body style="background-color:' . $days[1] . '">';
   ?>
```

That's using 1 array, but the question asks me to use two arrays. So I guess put the days of the week into another array, but ... I get confused at this point.

Full disclosure: This is a homework question.

Comment: Colour depending on what day it is.

Comment: What do you mean with `but the question asks me to use two arrays.`? So you NEED 2 arrays by any means necessary, no matter if its senseful or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
echo '<body style="background-color:' . $days[$today] . '">';
```

Comment: so $today is a predefined variable?

Comment: `$today` is variable that you have defined in your question. It gets values in range `0-6`.

Answer (score 1):

Array can consist of keys and values. So you can use $today as key, to get the corresponding value.
date('w') returns the day of the week as number, where Sunday is 0.

```
<?php 
$days = array(0 => "blue", 1 => "green"); 
$today = date('w'); 
echo '<body style="background-color:' . $days[$today] . '">';
?>
```

(code not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Use this php markup and make classes for different colors in css like below

**CSS**

```
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.green{background-color:green;}
..../*other colors*/
```

php function `date('w')` will return Numeric representation of the day of the week starting from Sunday as 0 which you can use to echo the proper class from the php array.  In this case you should put the name of the class for Sunday first, Monday second and so on..

**PHP**

```
   <?php 
       $days = array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow", "black", "purple", "white"); 
       echo '<body class="' . $days[date('w')] . '">';
   ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Lone, how about if start from Monday?